# Four-terminal resistor pinout?

Tags: resistors, shunt, current-sensing

Anyone can tell me (or preferably, point me to a source that explicitly shows) the pinout of the 4-pin current-sense resistors?

I'm seeing the datasheets for three different models (including [Rideon's FHR 4-2321](https://riedon.com/media/pdf/FHR4-2321.pdf), the [Powertron FHR 4-2321](http://www.vishaypg.com/doc?64246),and the [PBV-R005-F1-0.5](https://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/50-3961.pdf)) and I simply cannot believe that neither one of them shows the *actual pinout* !!!  (the Powertron datasheet does say "Standard Contact S", but a Google search for that shows nothing concrete)

[This page](https://www.powerstandards.com/tutorials/how-4-terminal-resistors-work-2/) gives a very good explanation of the intended use.  Except that they talk about terminal 1, 2, 3, and 4.  They do not explicitly relate T1,T2,T3,T4 to pin numbers (and their drawing doesn't look like Terminal N maps to pin N --- in any case, if we read the pins 1,2,3,4 from left to right)

Comment: Usually, the two outer terminals are where you apply the current, and the inner two are for the kelvin connection. I'm not completely confident in that, though.

Comment: Also notice that the PBV-R005 datasheet shows the package image with two terminals marked I and two marked U; these are common symbols for current and voltage respectively, which says to me to apply current to the I terminals and measure the voltage at the U terminals.

Comment: Hahaha --- a "race condition";  I was half-way writing precisely that comment about the I-U-U-I labels in the PBV datasheet.  But I was going to point out that I wasn't 100% sure about the labels, and also, that seems to be in contradiction with the terminals numbering in the "How 4-terminal resistors work" page.  So, you know, with the ambiguity, I preferred to ask and see if someone could point me to a more explicit diagram.

Comment: If you look at lab current shunts like http://www.redlion.net/sites/default/files/213/3900/APSCM%20Product%20Manual.pdf you see that the current and sense terminals are on the same termination block of the resistor, the 4 point feature being that the connection resistance of the current path screw doesn't affect the voltage measured across the sense terminals. I'd suspect that these shunts are similar in construction, in that the two leads at each side are part of a single leadframe that the resistor element is bonded to, and the fatter of the two pins is the designated current terminal.

Comment: @PhilG -- _"and the fatter of the two pins is the designated current terminal"_.  Nice detail!  I hadn't even noticed/paid attention to that detail;  in the 4-pin resistor I have, the two outer pins have a thicker "neck".  I guess at this point I'm convinced enough that the pinout is probably that: two outer pins for current, two inner pins to measure voltage  (still, if someone knows of a reference that explicitly shows the diagram, or someone has recently actually used one of these and know with certainty, please do post !!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at lab current shunts like this one

[image]

you see that the current and sense terminals are on the same termination block of the resistor, the 4 point feature being that the connection resistance of the current path screw doesn't affect the voltage measured across the sense terminals. I'd suspect that these shunts are similar in construction, in that the two leads at each side are part of a single leadframe that the resistor element is bonded to, and the fatter of the two pins is the designated current terminal.

[Here is an Ohmite](https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/res_cs3.pdf) data sheet that shows explicitly which pin is which.
[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

The larger pin would be more suitable for carrying current, so that would be the best indicator. In the event that the pins are the same size it probably wouldn't matter, they go to the same place. Usually the two inner pins are the kelvin connections.

[image]